# Obj C - Checking Current State of a Disclosure Arrow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton

I'm trying to differentiate between a disclose arrow being 'On' (pointed down) or 'Off' (pointed up). The posted code is completely wrong and just the general idea of what I want it to do.

```
- (IBAction)disclosureArrow:(NSControl *)sender{

if (disclosureArrow currentState:ON) {
    //action
}
```

IBOutlet id discloseArrow is attached to the disclose button in interface builder and it receives a command from IBAction that is also attached to the button. How do I check the button's current state ? (In regards to disclosure arrows.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe:

```
BOOL isOn = ([sender state] == NSOnState);
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: if (![disclosureArrow state] == NSOnState) That worked fine based on what you said, thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

So you have set a *custom image* as *button* as your `accessory view` of a `tableViewCell`? Is that correct? Are you using static cells? How do you change the arrows?

The most easy way is probably to change the `tag` of your `button` regarding to its state. When assigning the arrow up, you give it the tag 1. Else you give it the tag 2.

Than you could read it like that:

```
- (IBAction)disclosureArrow:(NSControl *)sender
{
  if (sender.tag == 1)
  {
  }
}
```